# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable while writing to a file in python

Tags: python

I am very much new to Python, all i was trying to run the shell command in my python script and was trying to write the result into an output file.

I am getting the following error while writing to the file.

Here is my sourcecode

```
total_count = subprocess.call("sed -n '$=' " +sourcePath, shell=True)

fo.write (" The total count on the Audit Report is " )
fo.write(string(total_count))
```

Error Message:

```
fo.write(string(total_count))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: You want to call `fo.write(str(total_count))` instead.

Comment: You probably also want to ask yourself why you imported `string` in the first place; most of its functionality is available as methods on `str`.

Comment: Hey Thank u Brian and Kevin, as i said, i just started learning Pyhton and its my ignorance to ask such a question